How to rotate a door smoothly
I'm trying to Rotate an Any door in my scenes by code. I need to rotate a door smoothly, but it happens instantly (without Rotating).I used the Lerp function, but nothing changed. I have two scripts. The first one is attached to the door.. It has two functions: DoorOpen and DoorClose. Here is my code.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Door : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] float speed;
    [SerializeField] float openAngle;
    [SerializeField] float closeAngle;
    
    Quaternion targetOpenRotation;
    Quaternion targetCloseRotation;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        targetOpenRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.y, openAngle, transform.rotation.z);
        targetCloseRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.y, closeAngle, transform.rotation.z);
    }

    public void DoorOpen()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetOpenRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);

    }

    public void DoorClose()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetCloseRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}


The second code I use for the purpose of Raycasting. is attached to the player.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class Interaction: MonoBehaviour
{
    bool doorOpened;
    private void Start()
    {
        doorOpened = false;

    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Ray from the center of screen
        Vector3 RayStartPosition = new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0);
        Ray cameraRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(RayStartPosition);

        //Distance to open a door
        float maxDistance = 3f;


        if (Physics.Raycast(cameraRay, out RaycastHit hit, maxDistance))
        {
            string objectTag = hit.collider.gameObject.tag;

            //Door open and close 
            if (objectTag == "Door" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                var door = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Door>();

                if (doorOpened)
                {
                    
                    door.DoorClose();
                    doorOpened = !doorOpened;

                }
                else
                {
                    door.DoorOpen();
                    doorOpened = !doorOpened;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}


I've tried to use Lerp and Slerp, but nothing changed.

DoorOpen and DoorClosed are only ever called once. Meaning they only move once, regardless of Lerp/Slerp.
You need to either put movement code in Update or use a [Corotuine] that gradually rotates the door. (FixedUpdate if the door uses physics for collision).
public class Door : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float speed;
    [SerializeField] float openAngle;
    [SerializeField] float closeAngle;
    
    Quaternion targetOpenRotation;
    Quaternion targetCloseRotation;
    bool isOpen;

    public void Start()
    {
        targetOpenRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.y, openAngle, transform.rotation.z);
        targetCloseRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.y, closeAngle, transform.rotation.z);
    }

    public void Update() {
        Quaternion currentTarget = isOpen ? targetOpenRotation : targetCloseRotation;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, currentTarget, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    public void DoorOpen()
    {
        isOpen = true;
    }

    public void DoorClose()
    {
        isOpen = false;
    }
}

(Also, nitpicking, but the door should contain an isOpen variable, not the Interaction class. Also, the check for the player hitting E should happen before the raycast, so the game doesn't waste time doing raycasts when the player won't even interact.)

Great answer, thank you!!! You've helped me a lot.

I have only one problem left. I want to use this script on ANY door i need, but if I attach the script to another door, nothing works. For example, i've created a new door, which i rotated to 90 degrees, when I press play, the door rotates automatically to x=0, y=0, z=0 (It becomes equal to the rotation of the first door on which I tested the script). I've made targetOpenRotation public and changed the initial values for the second door directly, but nothing works

@dmitryrubanov remove your doorOpened variable from the Interaction class (they're getting desynced when you have multiple doors) and instead call a new Door function instead of DoorOpen and DoorClose directly: public void ToggleDoor() { if (isOpen) DoorClose(); else DoorOpen(); }

thx you! U're my savior!!! Script works perfect and clear.
